# Continuous function mapping into itself

Tags: real-analysis, functions

my problem here is how to get from examples to a formal proof. Here is the question:

Let $X = (1, \infty)$ and $f: X\to \mathbb R$ be given by 
$$f(x)= \frac 12\left(x+\frac ax\right).$$ 
Show that if $a$ is in $(1,3)$, then $f$ maps into itself, i.e. $f(x)$ is in $X$ for all $x$ in $X$. I won't bother you with all the examples I tried to check that this is true, but I guess...I cannot write down an infinite number of examples on my paper (it would require too much paper...and time!) Anyhow, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I put a random tag since the software requires a tag

Comment: All you are trying to show is that f is positive if you plug in a positive number.

Comment: If x=1 and a=-100 f doesn't map into itself. While if x=32 and a=5 f maps into itself. So I can get any example we want. I just don't get why, for all x you can pick only a in (1,3) would do the trick

Comment: The problem isn't saying $a$ has to be in (1,3) for f to be positive. It is saying that if $a$ is in (1,3) then f is positive.

Comment: Unless the question was editted, it needs more than positive, it needs greater than 1, since $X=(1,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Take a derivative to find the location of the minimum of f. In this case $\sqrt{a}$, since $a\in(1,3)$. Now the minimum value of the function is $f(\sqrt{a})$, and you need to show that this is greater than 1 for $a\in(1,3)$. If the minimum is greater than 1, then all function vales are greater than 1.